# Setting a font size based on device width and height

Tags: android, textview, android-resolution

In my application i am displaying a CardView which has textview (account title). The card view height i am calculating based on device width.

Since i am setting the cardview height based on device width, i want to change the font size of textview (account title) to make font size consist based on card height.

**How to we apply font sizes for textview based on device width and height?**

Answer (score 0):

In your project resources create different values directories and call it for example `values-h600p` and put on it the dimensions resources that you will use on your styles or layouts for screens with height >= 600dp. 
That's the standard way to do it. Better explained here :

https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes

Answer (score 0):

Setting font size based on device dimensions is probably bad UX. You shouldn't prioritize "look" over user experience. You risk having a situation where the text is not legible but your UI looks "good"; users won't like that. Instead, consider redesigning your CardView so that your UI still looks good even when the text in question is too lengthy. Also font size is a delicate thing when it comes to UX and so you should try staying with a standard [TextAppearence](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes) style. Even in situations where you may have different layout for different screen sizes, you normally do not change font size (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes)

Additional advice:

You should take a look at the Google News app. Benchmarking other apps that do what you want to accomplish is usual good policy.